# Whats wrong with this query? not getting any errors

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, doctrine

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with the next query , first time using them. The foreach should display some titles from mysql db but it's not showing anything. I'm not getting any errors either.

```
<?php               
$industrey = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Industry")
           ->select("id, title")
           ->where("title = ? ", 'title')
           ->addWhere("id = ?", 'id')
           ->orderBy("ord ASC")
           ->execute(array());
?>
<div class="block banners blockpromo">
<h2>Industries</h2>
<?php foreach ($industrey as $industry): ?>
<li><?php echo link_to($industry['title'].'<span></span>', '@industry?industry_alias='.$industry['id'], array('title' => $industry['title']));?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: isn't order should be 1.select 2.from 3.where ?

Comment: 'Industry' is the table . id , title and ord is the structure . Pretty sure thats the right order.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL query by this ORM?

Comment: i'm not sure but should the select not be ->select('id','title')?

Comment: You are selecting where the id column equals the string "id" and the title column equals the string "title", did you mean to supply variables here? Also these where clauses are problem not necessary if you want to select all of the industries in the table.